# Trigger some action on system clock change?

Tags: linux, timezone, clock, events

I would like to have something occur - say, I would like to run a certain script - whenever the system clock is adjusted (hardware clock and/or offset from hardware clock, including the timezone). This could be through user action (e.g. `date -s`), or an automated adjustment such as an NTP daemon; I don't want to make any assumptions regarding the reason and circumstances for the change.

Is there a non-systemd-based mechanism  which does this?

Comment: Do you mean when the clock is adjusted, such as when NTP makes changes or something else? Your Q is a bit unclear at the moment.